# Add callback function to parent component from child component

Tags: reactjs

I got parent component and child component(tooltip component). In child component's componentdidmount, I want to add callback function to parent component to close child component. How can I add callback function to parent component from child component.

```
export default class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    render() {
        <div>
             sdf adfa sfdsf
             saf
             a sfdsaf sfsf safdsa
             asdf safdsaf safdsafasdf
             asdf safdsafdsafsadf
             asdf asfsadfdsafdsaf
             ..............
            <Child />
        </div>
    }
}

export default class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            IsShownTooltip: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        //want to add Parent div on click here to close popup with setstate
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            IsShownTooltip: true
        });
    }

    render() {
        <div onClick={this.onClick}>
            {this.state.IsShownTooltip && 
                <div>tooooooooooooooooltip text hererrrrrrrrrr</div>
            }
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli. Hi Gabriele. Sorry for wrong copy. I corrected code.

Comment: You could initialize state with showChild property in parent and then pass a callback function to toggle it to your child component and assign toggling on child click

Comment: Hi @JSEvgeny. I don't get it. How can I initialzie state with showChild property

Comment: Hi @zanhtet, check the following answer, it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the show/hide toggle functionality in Parent component like this.

1.Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';

export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        IsShownTooltip: false
    }
}

onClickToggle = () => {
    this.setState({
        IsShownTooltip: !this.state.IsShownTooltip,
    })
}
render() {
    return(
    <div>
         parent
         ..............
         <button onClick={() => this.onClickToggle()}>click</button>
        <Child IsShownTooltip={this.state.IsShownTooltip} onClickChild={() => this.onClickToggle()} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

2. Child.js

   ```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';

   export default class Child extends Component {

   render() {
     return(
       <div onClick={this.onClick}>
           <button onClick={() => this.props.onClickChild()}>click</button>
           {this.props.IsShownTooltip && 
               <div>tooooooooooooooooltip text hererrrrrrrrrr</div>
           }
       </div>
    )
   }}
   ```

   The code can be improved a lot, just for the output of your provided example, I wrote this. 
   Hope this will be helpful to you :)